# Android: Localizing japanese dates

Tags: android

I'm localizing my app's dates to Japanese.

I'm using the date format `yyyy\'年\'M\'月\'` for the result `2017年1月` (for January 2017) which is totaly fine. I've noticed though that if I use the format `yyyy\'年\'MMMM` I get the same result `2017年1月` which meens that Android knows to localize `MMMM` to the way months are to displayed i japanese without me having to postfix the year with the japanese char.

Unfortunatly I can't find a good reference on the rest of the format strings, fx. how to get the same result fro the YEAR format so instead of writing `yyyy\'年\'`for result `2017年`, I'll just have to write `YYYY`(which doesn't work) or something else.

Any ideas?

Comment: share some example date and its format

Comment: I think I actually did. It's all in the question. I'm not looking for help in code, just in format strings.